# LinkedIn Groups: post with link in title?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to post a new post to a group via the linkedin API and have a link in the title of the post?

I can't find any documentation on what is allowed or not in the title in the documentation here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api

Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that it is possible.

An example is here: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Now-new-website-FoodBarcelona-Restaurants-1446917.S.136723085?qid=90c4aa0a-fc9a-4934-b7e5-3d555133b8e5&trk=group_most_popular-0-b-ttl&goback=%2Egmp_1446917 (not sure if it's visible without being a member).

In the lists of questions the title is the link to the details page, but on the details page, there is a link shown in the end of the title.
Not sure though if that is passed as html or linkedin automatically parses links and converts them to html.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it; you can test by trying to create a post here:

http://simplelinkedin.fiftymission.net/demo/groups.php#groupCreatePost

When you add any HTML to the tile, the API responds with a 400 error:

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '\' (code 92) in start tag Expected a quote
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3,34]
```

Logically, I'm not sure how it would, as when you create a post via the API, it posts to a group on LinkedIn.com, and every group post title is itself a link to the full post itself within the group.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I wasn't able to find the createpost method there even after authenticating. Also when trying to join the "Simple LI" group I get this error: "LinkedIn->joinGroup(): bad data passed, $gid must be of type string". Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing that error on the link I posted, or in your own use of the code after downloading it?